# How do I get the UTC offset from a given timezone for a specific date

Tags: c#, nodatime

Here is a concrete example.

Date: August 8, 1963 5:37 AM
Timezone: America/Chicago

On this given date and timezone, the UTC offset was -6. But I'm getting -5 from NodaTime.

I tried multiple ways of calculating the UTC offset with NodaTime but they all return -5. Below is just one such thing I tried.

```
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
var localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(localEventDateTime);

ZoneLocalMappingResolvr customResolver = Resolvers.CreateMappingsolver(Resolvers.ReturnLater, Resolvers.ReturnStartOfIntervalAfter);
var zonedDateTime = zone.ResolveLocal(localDateTime, customResolver);
var result = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
```

What code can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you expect -6? Looking at [historic data](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago?year=1963), CDT started on 1963/04/28 and ended on 1963/08/27, so the time offset during that period was UTC-5. Do you mean you just want the base offset without consideration for DST?

Comment: Indeed - that's working fine as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm comparing the offset to two other sources that both return -6. Maybe they are the ones that are wrong! Wow! Anyway, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Did they perhaps give the *base* offset, and handle DST separately? If these are only sources and you're happy to quote them, I'd be interested in taking a look.